# Shall I go for 12.04 or 12.10 if I want stability and speed?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, system, versions

I think this might be the most annoying question for the pros here, but I'd really like to know which version is better if I'd like a super fast start-up and processing speed. I know it rather depends on the CPU, but the OS is important too. I dont really care for the long term support since I normally re-install my system once a year. I'd just like to choose a stable and fast OS and I have been reading all sorts of things, but no one has given a proper answer to my question/doubt.

Thanks a lot.

---

**UPDATE:** if someone has already asked this, then please merge this with that post and close it. Thanks.

Comment: use both and decide your self. I have used 12.04 and it was awesome. Then I upgraded to 12.10 and didn't find any issues. So it's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably read some reviews about the two versions and decide yourself. The reviews I enjoy the most reading are those from [dedoimedo.com](http://dedoimedo.com)